# Laravel Auth::attempt ok, but Route before('auth') fail

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I can login into my project by using `Auth::attempt`. 
However, after redirecting to another page with `Filter before => 'auth'` no user is logged in.  How can I persist the logged in user?

**Route.php**

```
Route::controller('mitarbeiter' , 'MitarbeiterController');
Route::get('intern', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    return View::make('texte.intern');
}));
```

**MitarbeiterController.php**

```
public function postLogin() {
    // Welche Daten werden für die Authentifizierung verwendet?
    $credentials = array(
        'login' => Input::get('login'), 
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );
    // Authentifizierung
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
        // Auth o.k.
        return Redirect::intended('intern');
    }
    else {
        // Auth fail
        return Redirect::intended('mitarbeiter')
            ->withInput();
    }       
}
```

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('mitarbeiter');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your sessions. Make sure they are working.

Comment: Shouldn't `return Redirect::intended('mitarbeiter')` instead be `return Redirect::to('mitarbeiter')`? As it is, if Auth fails your app will still try to lead the requested protected page.